# Ajax not going to the success in .net

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

please have a look I couldnt get in to the success in my code , dont know why?
something should be wrong with my set up, once I try to debugg it wont goes to the success

```
 var postCodeData = "_PostCode=" + $("#Postcode").val();
        //debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: "CheckGas/getStreetName/",
            type: "GET",
            data: postCodeData,
            success: function (data) {

                var res = JSON.stringify(data);
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log(jsonObj);
                // alert(objJson);
                //var jsonData = "hello world";

                var postcodeLength = $("#Postcode").val();

                //$("#StreetName").val() = jsonData;

                if (postcodeLength.length == 4) {
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(jsonObj)) {
                        console.log("HELLO WORLD");
                        $('#mapAndGas').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                        $('#gasResponse').css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    }
                }

                var matchVal = $("#Postcode").val();
                jsonObj.filter(function (item) {
                    if (item.PostCode == matchVal) {
                        $("#StreetName").append($('<option></option>').val(item.StreetName).html(item.StreetName));
                    }
                });

            },
            error:function()
        {
                alert(postCodeData);
        }
        });
```

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to look at the network request and see whether it is successful.  In IE for example, press F12 then click Network, then press the green Play button.

Comment: I did already, it goes to error, I am inspecting sth wrong with my data, any idea?

Comment: Post specifically what you see in the network tab.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to cover what you expected this code to do versus what you observed, and any error messages or helpful debug/troubleshooting information that is relevant.

Comment: Why your ajax request type is "GET"? If you use "GET", you should pass data through url, not through "data" parameter.

Comment: Post your function code for better undeerstanding.

Comment: Use Fiddler to check what is sent (is the URL what you expected?) and what is returned (maybe the server gave an error that gives a hint?). Please add those details to your question.

Comment: This happened to me and it was really painful to debug. Check the structure and content of what you're passing in -  maybe you have an invalid character or something.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is use your F12 developer tools and start looking at what the response is doing, another thing you should do is put a break point on getstreetname method to see what is going on. The next question is what is that method? Is it a web service? Once you find out the response is hitting your method in the backend code, you can then analyse it more. If you are using a web method, make sure that method is setup properly... Also, why don't you specify if its JSON or XML datatype??? Looks like the ajax call is not completely filled out.

Start out by debugging and let me know how that goes, and check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  for your references.

-G